# instance seems to ignore key

Tags: expl3, xtemplate

Here's basic example showing a) "instance will set some key in the template", and b) "The key–value list of⟨parameters⟩applies in the⟨new template⟩and cannot be changed whencreating an instance." I fail to understand the outcome I'm getting. I was expecting "hello world!" for both, with different brackets. And for b), I anticipated a warning telling the key was restricted. What am I amissing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xtemplate}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareObjectType{say}{1}

\DeclareTemplateInterface{say}{parent}{1}
{key : tokenlist}

\DeclareTemplateCode{say}{parent}{1}
{key = \l__say_key_tl}
{(#1~\tl_use:N\l__say_key_tl)}

% Manual:
% DeclareRestrictedTemplate{⟨object type⟩} {⟨parent template⟩} {⟨new template⟩}{⟨parameters⟩}
% Creates a copy of the⟨parent template⟩for the⟨object type⟩called⟨new template⟩.
%The key–value list of⟨parameters⟩applies in the⟨new template⟩and cannot be changed whencreating an instance.

\DeclareRestrictedTemplate{say}{parent}{child}
{key = world!}

\DeclareTemplateCode{say}{child}{1}
{key = \l__say_key_tl}
{\{#1~\tl_use:N\l__say_key_tl\}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% Manual:
% \DeclareInstance{⟨object type⟩} {⟨instance⟩} {⟨template⟩} {⟨parameters⟩}
% This function uses a⟨template⟩for an⟨object type⟩to create an⟨instance⟩.
% The⟨instance⟩will be set up using the⟨parameters⟩, which will set some of the⟨keys⟩in the⟨template⟩.

\ShowTemplateCode{say}{parent}
\DeclareInstance{say}{foo}{parent}{key=world!}
\UseInstance{say}{foo}{hello} % expected (hello~world)
\ShowInstanceValues{say}{foo}
%> \template code > say/parent=\protected\long macro:#1->(#1 \tl_use:N
%\l__say_key_tl ).
%<recently read> }
%l.36 \ShowTemplateCode{say}{parent}
%The instance 'foo' of object type 'say' has values:
%>  key  =>  world!
%>  from template  =>  parent.
%<recently read> }
%l.39 \ShowInstanceValues{say}{foo}
\ShowTemplateCode{say}{child}
\DeclareInstance{say}{bar}{child}{key=universe!}
\UseInstance{say}{bar}{hello} % expected {hello~world}
\ShowInstanceValues{say}{bar}
%> \template code > say/child=\protected\long macro:#1->\{#1 \tl_use:N
%\l__say_key_tl \}.
%<recently read> }                 
%l.41 \ShowTemplateCode{say}{child}
%LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMS+cmr on input line 4
%3.
%(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd
%File: omscmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
%)
%LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10> not available
%(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 43.
%The instance 'bar' of object type 'say' has values:
%>  key  =>  universe!
%>  from template  =>  child.
%<recently read> }                 
%l.44 \ShowInstanceValues{say}{bar}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right about the expected outcome: there are some bugs in the implementation here which mean it's not working as advertised. I'll see if I can work out a fix for all of them.

Comment: I get "hello world" if I add `\AssignTemplateKeys` to the template code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some issues in the code for restrictive templates. These are [now fixed](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/d0082f56fec0b58becc6c165e8d3f1b4ff61a729) in the development code, which will be released shortly.

As noted in a comment, you also need `\AssignTemplateKeys`. With the fixed code

```latex
\DeclareTemplateCode{say}{child}{1}
{key = \l__say_key_tl}
{\AssignTemplateKeys\{#1~\tl_use:N\l__say_key_tl\}}
```

works as expected.

Comment: bummer, I keep forgetting it.