# Why did xfrac change in 2021?

Tags: xfrac

In TeX Live 2020, and earlier, my MVE looked just the way I wanted:

[image: Good fractions]

but in TeX Live 2021, it looks like this:

[image]

notice how the second fraction, the sfrac in math mode, has changed.

I found that two lines has beed deleted in the `sty`-file.  I bet this is intentional by the developers, but why? Is it more aesthetic? Are there some typographical reasons that I should know, that might change my mind? I think one could revert the change be defining an `instance` with the old parameters. Could there be an `oldmath` setting in the package?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

A \(\frac12\) B \(\sfrac12\) C \sfrac12

\end{document}
```

Comment: These fractions are not intended for math mode.

Comment: @HenriMenke the xfrac docu starts with a math example.

Comment: @daleif, any opinion?

Comment: I think I might have 'overdone' a fix for another issue - I'm hoping https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/1045384888e696f46e89f3e91b7cd26413f10846 will sort this - let me do a bit of testing

Comment: Might take a few days for me to work out the full problem

Comment: @Gaussler I have nothing to do with xfrac

Comment: @daleif, you are listed as a (former) maintainer, so you probably were, at some point. I thought this was still the case.

Comment: @Gaussler not really, I think it was another of Mortens projects. Not sure how I got involved. Never even used the package

Comment: Thank you for saving me the trouble of posting the same question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The change arises as there was a [(long-standing) bug in `xtemplate`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595931/instance-seems-to-ignore-key/595957#595957), on which `xfrac` is built. Fixing the issue in `xtemplate` highlighted an issue in `xfrac`, which is now fixed but which means I need to address another issue in `xfrac`. This is fixed in the sources, but it may be a little while before a release. For the present, try

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareRestrictedTemplate { xfrac } { text } { math }
  {
    numerator-font      = \number \fam ,
    slash-symbol        = /            ,
    slash-symbol-font   = \number \fam ,
    denominator-font    = \number \fam ,
    scale-factor        = 0.7          ,
    scale-relative      = false        ,
    scaling             = true         ,
    denominator-bot-sep = 0 pt         ,
    math-mode           = true         ,
    phantom             = ( % )
  }
\DeclareInstance { xfrac } { mathdefault } { math }
  { numerator-top-sep = 0pt }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

A \(\frac12\) B \(\sfrac12\) C \sfrac12

\end{document}
```

which re-declares the appropriate parts of the mechanism.